# which python installer should I install for couchbase on windows 64 not amd processor

Tags: python, python-2.7, couchbase

I want to start working on Couchbase from Python, I am on this page https://pypi.python.org/pypi/couchbase#downloads which states that I need to install the windows installer and which includes everything I want.

the possible versions are:

```
File                                        Type    Py Version  Uploaded on Size
couchbase-1.2.2.tar.gz (md5)                Source      2014-07-02  254KB
couchbase-1.2.2.win-amd64-py2.6.exe (md5)   MS Windows installer    2.6 2014-07-02  493KB
couchbase-1.2.2.win-amd64-py2.7.exe (md5)   MS Windows installer    2.7 2014-07-02  492KB
couchbase-1.2.2.win-amd64-py3.2.exe (md5)   MS Windows installer    3.2 2014-07-02  493KB
couchbase-1.2.2.win-amd64-py3.3.exe (md5)   MS Windows installer    3.3 2014-07-02  490KB
couchbase-1.2.2.win32-py2.6.exe (md5)   MS Windows installer    2.6 2014-07-02  441KB
couchbase-1.2.2.win32-py2.7.exe (md5)   MS Windows installer    2.7 2014-07-02  441KB
couchbase-1.2.2.win32-py3.2.exe (md5)   MS Windows installer    3.2 2014-07-02  441KB
couchbase-1.2.2.win32-py3.3.exe (md5)   MS Windows installer    3.3 2014-07-02  435KB
```

I am working on windows 7 intel processor 64 bit and python 2.7

the first one is not for windows

the second, third, fourth, and fifth is for amd processor but i have intell processor

the sixth one is for python 2.6 but i have python 2.7

the seventh one is for python 2.7 with 32 bit but i have 46 bit processor

the eighth and ninth are for python 3.x but i have python 2.7

#### my question

it seems that the sixth one is the best of the option but still it is not 64 bit.

is there any other resource where i can find the 64 bit python 2.7 for couchbase?

thanks

Answer (score 2):

`amd64` is the original name for the 64bit x86 extensions added by AMD, and later adopted by Intel, who (eventually) branded it "Intel64". So you should use `couchbase-1.2.2.win-amd64-py2.7.exe`.

Comment: i am afraid that i am late, i already installed the seventh one. what should i do now please?